# How Do You Expire A Memcached Entry On Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, caching, heroku, memcached

I am using action caching on my Rails 3 app on Heroku with the :expires_in option.  I've tried calling expire_action, directly in the controller upon update, and within a sweeper.  Nothing seems to expire the cache entry properly.

In my controller:

```
caches_action :embed, :if => Proc.new { |c| c.request.format.js? || c.request.format.rss? }, :expires_in => 5.minutes
```

In my action:

```
expire_action :action => :embed, :format => :js
```

And I've also attempted it in a sweeper, attempting to use the url generator to get the exact key:

```
expire_action obj_embed_url(@obj.unique_token)
```

I wonder if it is Heroku using the Varnish cache layer, which you can't expire.  (The cache clearly expires after the 5 minutes, because I can see the content update.)  It appears that I have the memcached add-on configured correctly (using the Dalli gem; config.cache_store = :dalli_store), and I can see the appropriate environment variables...

```
$ heroku config |grep MEM 
MEMCACHE_PASSWORD     => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
MEMCACHE_SERVERS      => xxx.xxx.northscale.net
MEMCACHE_USERNAME     => appxxxxxx%40heroku.com
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Varnish will only cache files with a Cache-control header set.  If you're running on Cedar, are you sure this hasn't cached to the filesystem? (Re-deploying will create a new dyno and clear this as a test)

Comment: The app is on bamboo-ree-1.8.7.  Yes, I wanted to avoid Varnish because of the inability to expire sooner than the cache-control length by using memcached (as it's in memory).

Answer (score 1):

finally figured this out.

Heroku's paths must not be matching up with the expire create/expire calls.  so if you specify the path in the cache creation, and call that path specifically in the expire, it will work.  also i had to use "expire_fragment" instead of "expire_action".  here's my code:

in your controller:

```
caches_action :load, :up, :juice, :fresh, :cache_path => :custom_cache_path.to_proc

def custom_cache_path
  path = "#{params[:controller]}/#{params[:action]}"
  path += "/#{params[:id]}" if params[:id]
  path += "/#{params[:sha]}" if params[:sha]
  path
end
```

in the expiring method:

```
expire_fragment "serve/up/#{@site.id}"
expire_fragment "serve/fresh/#{@site.secret}"
```